# Database upgrade from SQL Server 2000 to 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

We had upgrade the database from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2008 by installing SQL Server 2008 on our test server. Prior to this we used query analyzer. We disabled that query analyzer.

At that time we got some errors in stored procedures like `dateinterval.minute` method. I have just replaced that with new SQL Server 2008 functions. Now error has stopped. But when we installed SQL Server 2008 on live server that error has not occurred. Query Analyzer is active here.

Could you please tell me the reason for this? Was that error on test server occurring due to disabled Query Analyzer?

Best regards,

Pooja Sharma

Comment: `dateinterval.minute` is a .NET function sql server equlant will be `DATEADD`. dateinterval.minute never existed in sql server 2000.

Comment: hi, the method is like this  DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute, AS_D_SentToXBuilder, @CURDATE).I have replaced it with Minute.

Comment: yep this should fix the issue, `DateInterval.Minute` is a .NET function, dont know why it was there but it should have been `DATEADD(MINUTE, value, Value)` anyway